# Netsh delete all urlacl reservations of a specific port

Tags: c#, nancy, self-hosting, netsh

is there any way to delete every urlacl reservation of a specific port.

I mean something like this is possible (customer constelation):

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:55521/ user="everyone"

netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:55521/ user="everyone"
```

Now I would like to delete every reservation of port 55521, this could be any ip constelation!

By the way I am doing this in a c# application with a nancy self host.

Answer (score 21):

to show the urls:

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

to delete a url:

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://localhost:55521/
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the solution from 0x53olution, an easy way to get all acls in a list is running PowerShell:

```
netsh http show urlacl | Select-String -Pattern "55521"
```

I copied the output to a temporary file and deleted the `Reserved URL     :` part, then you can do:

```
Get-Content <temp-file>.txt | % {netsh http delete urlacl url=$_}
```

The saving to a temporary file part could be skipped with some `-replace` action.

If you want to find more rules, you can use for example `Select-String -Pattern "55521|55522|55523"` instead.